# Scroll to a position and set left & right arrow in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, pagination, scrollview

I have following numbered pages, when user on a page, initial pagination number must be the user current page number. i have used

```
    <ScrollView ref={(view) => this._scrollView = view}>
    <View style={somestyle}><Text>1</Text></View>
    <View style={somestyle}><Text>2</Text></View>
     .
     .
     .
     .
    <View style={somestyle}><Text>9</Text></View>
    </ScrollView>
:
:
    this.refs._scrollView.scrollTo({x: 5, y: 0, animated: true})
```

(for 5th page) but not worked.
 Second question is how to add left< and right > arrow in scrollview
[image: Scroll view image]

Comment: actually added in ref

Comment: What is this `getScrollResponder()`

Comment: some code got from internet now removed

Comment: can you show the full component code please.

Comment: do we have any option for scroll to a position.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I have created you an example of how to add pagination with arrows to `ScrollView`,
It can be simplified and modified.

I did not add arrows but for simplification purposes, I use text instead  like this 
`<Text> Left Arrow </Text>` .
You add arrows using `Icon` or `Image` instead of `Text`.

Regarding your question :

> initial pagination number must be the user current page number

You can get the current `xOffset` by using `this.state.currentXOffset` which was set in the `<ScrollView onScroll={this._handleScroll} >` and setting it in the `_handleScroll` function. You can do your conditional for current page number there if you like.

Full code below, you can copy and paste the component as it only handles pagination, then modify what you want.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView, TouchableHighlight} from 'react-native';    

export default class ForTest extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      scrollViewWidth:0,
      currentXOffset:0
    }
  }

  _handleScroll = (event) => {
    console.log('currentXOffset =', event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x);
    newXOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x
    this.setState({currentXOffset:newXOffset})
  }

  leftArrow = () => {
    eachItemOffset = this.state.scrollViewWidth / 10; // Divide by 10 because I have 10 <View> items
    _currentXOffset =  this.state.currentXOffset - eachItemOffset;
    this.refs.scrollView.scrollTo({x: _currentXOffset, y: 0, animated: true})
  }

  rightArrow = () => {
    eachItemOffset = this.state.scrollViewWidth / 10; // Divide by 10 because I have 10 <View> items 
    _currentXOffset =  this.state.currentXOffset + eachItemOffset;
    this.refs.scrollView.scrollTo({x: _currentXOffset, y: 0, animated: true})
  }

  render() {
    //console.log('scrollViewWidth = ', this.state.scrollViewWidth)
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Page Works!</Text>

        <View style={{flex:1, flexDirection:'row', justifyContent:'center'}}>

          <TouchableHighlight
            style={{alignItems: 'flex-start', paddingTop:20}}
            onPress={this.leftArrow}>
            <Text> Left Arrow </Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>

          <ScrollView 
            contentContainerStyle={{backgroundColor:'yellow', alignItems: 'center'}}
            horizontal={true}
            pagingEnabled={true}
            ref="scrollView"
            onContentSizeChange={(w, h) => this.setState({scrollViewWidth:w})}
            scrollEventThrottle={16}
            scrollEnabled={false} // remove if you want user to swipe
            onScroll={this._handleScroll}
          >
            <View style={styles.somestyle}><Text>1</Text></View>
            <View style={styles.somestyle}><Text>2</Text></View>
            <View style={styles.somestyle}><Text>3</Text></View>
            <View style={styles.somestyle}><Text>4</Text></View>
            <View style={styles.somestyle}><Text>5</Text></View>
            <View style={styles.somestyle}><Text>6</Text></View>
            <View style={styles.somestyle}><Text>7</Text></View>
            <View style={styles.somestyle}><Text>8</Text></View>
            <View style={styles.somestyle}><Text>9</Text></View>
            <View style={styles.somestyle}><Text>10</Text></View>
          </ScrollView>

          <TouchableHighlight
            style={{alignItems: 'flex-end', paddingTop:20}}
            onPress={this.rightArrow}>
            <Text> Right Arrow </Text>
          </TouchableHighlight>

        </View>

      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  somestyle: {
    paddingVertical:10,
    paddingHorizontal:20,
    margin:10,
    borderWidth:1,
    borderRadius:1,
    borderColor:'black'
  }
})
```

I hope this helps.

**NOTE:** Im not quite sure this is what you should use for your application. I think you are looking to use something like `FlatLists` (which inherit from `VirtualizedList`) instead of `ScrollViews`.  `VirtualizedList` has a scrollToIndex function which is much more perceptive. Whereas, ScrollView's scrollTo expects `x` and `y` parameters meaning that you would have to calculate the exact spot to scroll to - which I had shown in the code example above(with padding style its even more complicated).

Comment: Your answer lead to what i need. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There has been modification in calculation of scroll view width

```
onContentSizeChange({ (width) => setScrollViewWidth(width - layoutWidth) }
```

**With functional components**

```
  const [scrollViewWidth, setScrollViewWidth] = useState(0);
  const [currentXOffset, setCurrentXOffset] = useState(0);
  const [layoutWidth, setLayoutWidth] = useState(0);

  const scrollViewRef = useRef<ScrollView>(null);

  const _handleScroll = (event: NativeSyntheticEvent<NativeScrollEvent>) => {
    const newXOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x;
    setCurrentXOffset(newXOffset);
  };


  const handleLeftArrow = () => {
    const eachItemOffset = scrollViewWidth / 10;
    const _currentXOffset = currentXOffset - eachItemOffset;
    scrollViewRef.current?.scrollTo({
      x: _currentXOffset,
      y: 0,
      animated: true,
    });
  };

  const handleRightArrow = () => {
    const eachItemOffset = scrollViewWidth / 10;
    const _currentXOffset = currentXOffset + eachItemOffset;
    scrollViewRef.current?.scrollTo({
      x: _currentXOffset,
      y: 0,
      animated: true,
    });
  };

  return (
     <View>
        {currentXOffset > 0 && (
        <Entypo
          name="chevron-thin-left"
          size={18}
          color={theme.colors.white}
          onPress={handleLeftArrow}
        />
      )}
    <ScrollView
        ref={scrollViewRef}
        horizontal
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        fadingEdgeLength={80}
        onLayout={(event) => setLayoutWidth(event.nativeEvent.layout.width)}
        onContentSizeChange={(width) => setScrollViewWidth(width - layoutWidth)}
        onScroll={_handleScroll}>
     
            ...

      </ScrollView>
      {currentXOffset < scrollViewWidth && (
        <Entypo
          name="chevron-thin-right"
          size={18}
          color={theme.colors.white}
          onPress={handleRightArrow}
        />
      )}
  </View>
)
```